# #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Tags: php, mysql

Can the people of the internet help me with MySQL

Error

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`user_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`username` VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,
`password` VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,
`first_name` VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,
`last_name` VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,
`email` VARCHAR( 1024 ) NOT NULL ,
`active` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE = innodb
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

Comment: You are sure that this query has the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It clearly says in the error **there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key**.

Add **PRIMARY KEY (user_id)** at the end and it should work.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`user_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`username` VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,
`password` VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,
`first_name` VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,
`last_name` VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,
`email` VARCHAR( 1024 ) NOT NULL ,
`active` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
) ENGINE = innodb;
```